# Can $\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx =\frac{a+b}{2} $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a,b]\to (0,+\infty )$ a continous function and $\int^b_a f(x)\,dx = 1$
Can $\int^b_a xf(x)\,dx =\frac{a+b}{2} $ ?
I do not know if it is true or not , but if it is true it would help me to solve a problem.

Comment: You could choose $f(x)=\frac{a+b}{2(b-a)x}$ but maybe that's not valid because the domain should be $\left[a,b \right]$.

Comment: For $a=1,b=2$, $f(x)=(n+1)x^n\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$, we have $\int_a^b{xf(x)dx}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}\frac{2^{n+2}-1}{2^{n+1}-1}$. For large $n$ this number is greater than $3/2$. However, if $f(x)=f(a+b-x)$ for each $x$ (ie $f$ is symmetric), the statement is true.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ fixed (they are the way the question is written)?  If you want them to vary, please make this clear.  How is the function $f$ quantified?  Is this for all $f$ or some $f$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the denstiy function $f$ of the uniform distrbution on $[a,b]$, which is given by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}\cdot1_{[a,b]},$$
where $1_{[a,b]}$ denotes the indicator function on the interval $[a,b]$ (you can of course neglect the indicator function when you just consider the interval $[a,b]$). Thus the first condition
$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathbb dx=1$$is satisfied since it is a density function and the second on is the expected value of a random variable $X$ with such a distribution:
$$\int_a^b x\cdot f(x)\mathbb dx=\mathbb E(X)=\frac{a+b}{2}.$$

Comment: it is true in this particular case but it may not be in the general case

Comment: In which kind is this particular and what do you mean by the "general case"? It holds for all $a<b$.

Comment: his assersion is true if $f$ is exactly the density function of a uniform probability. I think that the question is if it is true for $any$ $f$ such that $\int_a^bf=1 $

Comment: For me the question sounded like "is there any function that satisfies...". But you are right, the question is not that clear and it could also be interpreted in the way you did. I think the OP should clearify his question.

Comment: Could you details please?@mag

Comment: Check the edit for details. I interpreted your question in the way I wrote in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary continuous function. The answer is not Take $f(x)=\text{sin}x$ and $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $b=\pi$